# google speech cannot find module

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to pipe the output of a microphone, which is plugged into a Tessel2 microcontroller, to the @google-cloud/speech api.

I'm using a Windows 8 OS.

I keep getting this error:

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/remote-script/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v48-linux-mipsel/grpc_node.node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/remote-script/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/grpc_extension.js:1:205)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

It's looking for a Linux folder, but when I look in that path I have a folder called "node-v48-win32-ia32".

Does anyone have any recommendations to fix this issue?

I get this error even if I just require the api:

```
const google_speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')({
projectId: "voice-controlled-translator",
keyFilename: __dirname + "/voice-controlled translator-1daea28cb9c9.json"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Silly question, have you run `npm i` recently?</s>

Edit 1: Ah, OS differences. Running `npm i` from the target OS would probably fix it if you can do so.

Edit 2: Did some more digging, seems like gRPC doesn't provide a pre-built binary for your target architecture. I ran `npm i grpc --target_platform="linux" --target_arch="mipsel"` which yielded a 404 on trying to download said prebuilt binary. It did attempt to create this binary but whether or not that will work is beyond my ability to test as I don't have such a device lying around. Definitely try it and report back though.

grpc-node does seem to have a pure JS implementation listed here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node
You might try using it. `npm i @grpc/js-core`
You'll likely need to do some tweaking to `@google-cloud/speech` though.